# Only return the value instead of {'this' : 5} in Django

Tags: django

Sorry for the unclear title.

Here is my **joueur.py**

```
def vie_pourcentage_user (self):
    viepourcentageuser = (self.user.profile.vie * 100) / self.user.profile.vie_max
    return {'viepourcentageuser': int(viepourcentageuser)}


def energie_pourcentage_user (self):
    energiepourcentageuser = (self.user.profile.energie * 100) / self.user.profile.energie_max
    return {'viepourcentageuser': int(energiepourcentageuser)}
```

Here is my **view.py**

```
def index(request):
    viepourcentageuser = joueur.vie_pourcentage_user(request)
    energiepourcentageuser = joueur.energie_pourcentage_user(request)

    return render(request, 'base.html', {
        'viepourcentageuser': viepourcentageuser,
        'energiepourcentageuser': energiepourcentageuser,
    })
```

Here is what I see :

```
{'viepourcentageuser': 100}
```

Here is what I would like to see :

```
100
```

Sorry I know this is basics but it seemed like I missed something. Thanks !

Comment: It's returning that because *that is what you explicitly wrote in the return statement*. If you only want to return the value, then just do that.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm looking for, only returning the value, but how ?

Comment: Why not just `return int(viepourcentageuser)`, if that's what you want to return?

Comment: Do you mean that you want only the value to be visible in the template? in that case just put `{{ viepourcentageuser }}` in the template.